# json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String with AWS Lambda JAVA

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'am trying to parse the 'Body' from a POST request with a Java Lambda.
I'am stuck on this error for a while.

```
 org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

But the Body when logged look like that :

```
{"body":{"email":"test@test.com"}}
```

**Witch should work with the parsing i'am doing right ?
The weird thing is the insert is working on local with JUNIT but not online after on AWS.**

```
@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
    logger = context.getLogger();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    Number user_id = null;
    String birthdate = null;
    List<Number> company_id = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String email = null;
    String employment_status = null;
    String firstname = null;
    String lastname = null;
    String login = null;
    String profile = null;
    List<Number> site_id = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String validation_status = null;
    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();

    Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    String filterExpression = "";
    String RegionAWS = REGION.toString();
    client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(RegionAWS).build();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("LI_user");
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject event = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        logger.log(event.toJSONString());
        if (event.get("body") != null) {
            JSONObject bod = (JSONObject)parser.parse((String)event.get("body"));
         //   JSONObject bod = (JSONObject) event.get("body");
            if ( bod.get("id") != null) {
                user_id = (Number)bod.get("id");
            }
            if ( bod.get("birthdate") != null) {
                birthdate = (String)bod.get("birthdate");
            }
            if ( bod.get("email") != null) {
                email = (String) bod.get("email");
            }
            if ( bod.get("employment_status") != null) {
                employment_status = (String) bod.get("employment_status");
            }
            if ( bod.get("firstname") != null) {
                firstname = (String) bod.get("firstname");
            }
            if ( bod.get("lastname") != null) {
                lastname = (String) bod.get("lastname");
            }
            if ( bod.get("login") != null) {
                login = (String) bod.get("login");
            }
            if ( bod.get("profile") != null) {
                profile = (String) bod.get("profile");
            }
            if ( bod.get("validation_status") != null) {
                validation_status = (String) bod.get("validation_status");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You already had `logger.log(event.toJSONString());` as `event` is a `JSONObject`.

So why not replacing `JSONObject bod = (JSONObject)parser.parse((String)event.get("body"));`
with
`JSONObject bod = (JSONObject)event.get("body");`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
JSONObject bod = (JSONObject)parser.parse((String)event.get("body"));
```

with

```
JSONObject bod = (JSONObject)event.get("body");
```

if `event` is always an instance of `JSONObject` (as it seems granted, otherwise you would get a ClassCast at `JSONObject event = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);`)

You see logged

```
{"body":{"email":"test@test.com"}}
```

just because of `logger.log(event.toJSONString());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks you i have progress. 
But now its seem like when i send the data on JSON format with Postman, that he receive a stringified version of the body. I get this data on cloudwatch logs :

```
     "resource": "/users",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "stageVariables": null,
    "body": "{\n \"id\": 5,\n \"company_id\": [\n    1\n  ],\n \"email\": \"test@test.com\",\n \"employment_status\": \"FULL-TIME\",\n \"firstname\": \"Sebastien\",\n \"lastname\": \"LALALLALA\",\n \"login\": \"test@test.com\",\n \"profile\": \"FULL-TIME\",\n \"site_id\": \"55\",\n \"birthdate\": \"1985.05.05\",\n \"validation_status\" : \"COMPLETE\"\n}\n"
}
```

And this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Comment: Are you sending a raw json body from Postman? Did you set an `contentType` header?
If the structure of the request is stable, you could also consider using a POJO instead than consuming from an `InputStream` and using so many typecasts, i.e. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-pojo.html

Comment: Hello, yes i'am sending raw json body and content type is set to application/json